# I'm having some problems when I try localhost:3000 for programming with Google Chrome Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, localhost, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having many problems when I try use my localhost:3000 for programming in Ruby On Rails 4. 
When I put in the Chrome browser in my Mac OS X "El Capitan".
This redirect's of this link

```
http://www.free-merchants.com/partner/promokod_aliexpress-by-alibabacom#e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5-http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
```

and then automaticallyfor the other called: `http://localhost/to.php?subid=31`

I think i have a virus. Anyone has this?

Comment: Yes, you have malware, and this question is off-topic here. Get [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/) or the like.

Comment: What research did you do? What have you tried? What didn't work with the steps that you tried? You need to read "[ask]", and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. As is your question is poorly asked and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The anti malware bytes works! thank's guy's!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have a virus.

Tips for you to remove malware: 
https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-mac-os-x-virus/

You can also make a Genius Bar appointment and bring your Mac to Apple Store.
https://getsupport.apple.com/

Lastly, if you need an anti-virus software:
http://download.cnet.com/Sophos-Antivirus-for-Mac-Home-Edition/3000-2239_4-75328306.html?tag=mncol%3Btxt